# Using varargs in Julia on @evalpoly

Tags: julia

I want to feed a set of varargs into @evalpoly. I tried the following:

```
tup = (1,2,3,4,5);
@evalpoly(40, tup...)
```

But this gives a BoundsError. However, according to the Standard Library, @evalpoly(z, c...) gives a polynomial evaluation. Is the `...` used in the Standard Library definition different from the usual varargs syntax? Or am I simply misusing the varargs syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Julia @evalpoly macro with varargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077057/julia-evalpoly-macro-with-varargs)

Comment: @MattB.: Definitely a duplicate! Thanks for pointing it out. I'll close this shortly.